# Cant valid email textfield java

Tags: java, jtextfield

My problem is that i want to check if email textfield contains char "@".How am i supposed to do it?I also want to check if other textfields such as name, username, password are empty.Thanks alot in advance for your help. This application blowed my mind!

```
   private JButton signupButton;
private JTextField name;
  private JTextField email;
  private JTextField username;
private JPasswordField pass;

private UserManager userManager;

public SignUpFrame (UserManager userManager){
super("Please fill in your Data");

userManager = new UserManager();

signupButton = new JButton("Sign Up!");
signupButton.addActionListener(new signupButtonListener());

 name = new JTextField(15);

 email = new JTextField(15);

 username = new JTextField(15);

pass = new JPasswordField(15);



 JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

     mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
  mainPanel.add(name);
   mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
     mainPanel.add(email);
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
      mainPanel.add(username);
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
   mainPanel.add(pass);
    mainPanel.add(signupButton);

    this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
   this.pack();
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);







   }



    class signupButtonListener implements ActionListener{

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    String nam,emai,id,psw;

        nam = name.getText();
       emai= email.getText();
     id = username.getText();
 psw = pass.getText();

User u1 = new User(nam,emai,id,psw);

 UserManager.userList.add(u1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a TextField is empty you can use if statements like:

```
if(name.getText().length() > 0){ nam = name.getText(); }
...
```

And for checking if there a char @ in your email TextField you can use the .contains() method:

```
emai= email.getText();
if(emai.contains("@")){ ... }
```

I hope i was able to help you..

Comment: Generally you would use the String.trim() method first before checking the length.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an if to test what the field hold ie

```
if(nam.equals("")){
//alert the user

}
```

You can do this with all the fields.

You could possible use regular expression for the email - something like

```
String emailreg = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

 Boolean result = emailAddress.matches(emailreg);
if(result == true){
//email is valid
}
```

Hope this helps.